# Hot-encoding: missing columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have training set of 1000000 records and a testing set of 100. In order to create a recommendation system, I have created two dataframes that are organized as such:

```
[in]print(training_df.head(n=5))

[out]                     product_id
transaction_id                      
0000001                   [P06, P09]
0000002         [P01, P05, P06, P09]
0000003                   [P01, P06]
0000004                   [P01, P09]
0000005                   [P06, P09]
```

I then used sklearn to create a matrix with the product_id's as columns and the transaction_id's as rows(index).

Here is the code:

```
# Create a matrix for the transactions
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
training_df1 = training_df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(training_df.pop('product_id')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=training_df.index))
```

The product_id's are P01-P10. The problem is that P04 and P08 are absent from the training data, so my training_df1 has only 8 columns instead of 10. How can I add the two columns and fill them with 0's for all transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass predefined product-ids `P01-P10` as classes when initializing the *MultiLabelBinarizer*, and thus the output will always include these categories as columns:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
​
product_ids = ['P{:02d}'.format(i+1) for i in range(10)]
print(product_ids)
# ['P01', 'P02', 'P03', 'P04', 'P05', 'P06', 'P07', 'P08', 'P09', 'P10']
​
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=product_ids)
training_df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(training_df['product_id']),
                              columns=mlb.classes_,
                              index=training_df.index))
```

[image]

---

To get the matrix back only:

```
training_df.drop('product_id', 1).join(
    pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(training_df['product_id']), columns=mlb.classes_, index=training_df.index)
)
```

[image]

Comment: I get 'code'(Key Error:'product_id'). Also, I dont want to return the 'product_id' column, only the matrix.

Comment: It's likely you have popped out the `product_id` column from `training_df` by using `pop` method, I wouldn't recommend using it as it modifies `training_df` and give you problem like this. so try to rebuild it. Besides, do you need the `transaction_id` column, or just the P01-P10?

Comment: Ok, I think youre right, I will rebuild the df and try again- but yes it would be helpful to keep the transaction_id column, however including the product_id column gets a bit redundant as the data is already there.

Comment: You can chain `.set_index('transaction_id')` after to set `transaction_id` as index.